# Torque on a current loop in a magnetic field, could you please explain the derivation and concept?

Tags: electromagnetism, forces, electric-current, torque

Torque=mxB
Consider a rectangle loop pqrs of sides l and b , where pq and RS are perpendicular to field , I is the current, B is field , imagine that this loop is placed between 2 magnets.

[image]

Force experienced F=Bil where l is the length of rectangular loop

Comment: Sides pq and rs experience equal and opposite forces, separated by a perpendicular distance qr. The forces therefore constitute a couple. I suggest that you read up about the moment of a couple.